# Where can i find wordpress auto update code flows?

Tags: plugin-development, functions, code, automatic-updates

I want to see how WordPress auto update works in code . which WordPress file or function performs auto core update? I have read

```
http://halfelf.org/2011/how-the-wordpress-upgrade-works/
```

I have understood theoretically. but want to look code !

Comment: Me too. Nice question +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are seeking for is located in the `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php`. There is a bunch of classes regarding all updates.